# How to de-brand Ubuntu?

Tags: uninstall, branding

I am working on an Ubuntu Mod, and I would like to change the name/splash screen/login screen/etc in order to make it a more customized environment.  I've been able to change all of the names shown via the terminal, but no luck as of yet using gconftool-2 to change anything else.  Am I missing something?

This is what I have so far - https://github.com/seanmrice/6buntu-Mod

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remastersys is a lot better than Reconstructor, in my opinion.

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1073838

Comment: That thread is pretty out of date.

Comment: Downvoted: Out of date.

Answer (score 4):

Have a look at [Reconstructor](https://projects.lumentica.com/projects/reconstructor/wiki). The hosted version is paid, but a standalone desktop version is available too that allows you to customise distributions. Might be an easier way of changing branding.