# How can I rebrand Ubuntu?

Tags: branding

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to de-brand Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/32248/how-to-de-brand-ubuntu)

I want to re-brand ubuntu for my college. I Need to change logo and other things from Ubuntu to College logo.

I am going to implement ubuntu in Universities and starting with my college.

Can anyone help me, how I can re-brand ubuntu for my college?